# Adding True/False Boolean expression into program. (Python)

Tags: python

This is my program:

```
import random

def main():
print('Generating 100 random numbers, this program will determine how many are even and how many are odd.')
for count in range(1):
    even = 0
    odd = 0
    for count in range(100):
        numbers = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(numbers)
        if numbers % 2 == 0:
            even += 1
        else:
            odd += 1
print('Out of 100 random numbers,', even, 'are even and', odd, 'are odd.')

main()
```

Basically, what it does is that it prints out 100 random numbers and tell me how many are even and how many are odd. The program works perfectly, the only problem is that I have to use the " return True/False " Boolean value expression for the assignment.

I know I have to add another define function into the program if I'm going to do this, but I'm not sure on how to do it.

Does anyone know how to incorporate the True/False Boolean expression into this program?

Comment: Do you mean you have to return a hundred pairs of (number, odd/even)?

Comment: The names of variables are important, in your code `numbers` sound(s) odd...  Further, could you clarify the exact term of the requirements your code has to satisfy, possibly using cut&paste?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a little helper function like

```
# Longer function, but satisfies the requirements of using True/False and return
def isEven(x):    
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Then you can use this in your `main` function

```
for count in range(100):
    numbers = random.randint(1, 100)
    print(numbers)
    if isEven(numbers):  # Notice we're using the helper function here
        even += 1
    else:
       odd += 1
```

Comment: Oh he means "assignment" as in "schoolwork assignment" - makes sense now

Comment: Maybe instead you could just `return not x % 2`? Or do you have to use `True` and `False` directly?

Comment: @ThaneBrimhall That's how I originally had it, but I read the requirement of *"have to use the " return True/False " Boolean value expression for the assignment."* and interpreted that to mean they literally had to return `True` or `False`, but I could be mistaken.

Comment: Yeah. Yay for "learning" that ruins otherwise brilliant programmers by trying to teach them things...

Comment: Thanks Cyber, I finally got the requirement completed.                       @Aralox Haha sorry, I should've specified that this was an homework question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_even(x):    
    return not x % 2

"""
An alternate way using explicit True/False
def is_even(x):
    if not x % 2:
        return True
    return False
"""

def count_odds_evens():
    for _ in xrange(100):  # use range if using Python 3.x
        num = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(num)
        if is_even(num):
            even += 1
        else:
            odd += 1
    return even, odd


if __name__ == '__main__':
    evens, odds = count_odds_evens()
    print('Out of 100 random numbers, {} are even and {} are odd.'.format(evens, odds))
```

A slightly more idiomatic version. USing an `if __name__ == '__main__'` allows to use the functions you created in other programs without executing them immediately.

Answer (score -2):

The code should look like this:

```
import random
def main():
    even,odd = 0,0
    print('Generating 100 random numbers, this program will determine how many are even and how many are odd.')
    for count in range(100):
        numbers = random.randint(1, 100)
        print(numbers)
        if numbers % 2 == False:
            even += 1
        else:
            odd += 1
"""
 Alternative checking odd in if
 if numbers % 2 == True:
            odd += 1
        else:
            even += 1
"""
    print('Out of 100 random numbers,', even, 'are even and', odd, 'are odd.')

main()
```

Comment: All you did was make `even` and `odd` global. How does that improve the program?

Comment: @IanAuld now the program is working , it is improved

Comment: The program was already working, problem is that he needs to use True and False

Comment: Now you have put them back inside the function so all you did was use tuple assignment instead of normal assignment. Have you read the OP"s question?

Comment: Now i think its uses True and False